# What should an OP do if his post being locked indefinitely?

Tags: support, moderation, locking

What should an OP do if his question on programmers.stackexchange.com being locked by a moderator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Stop doing whatever you were doing that resulted in the question being locked.
2. Raise a question here on meta - with a link to the question concerned so we know what you are talking about.
3. E-mail "team+meta.programmers@stackexchange.com" with your issue. This isn't seen by the moderators so you can say what you like about us ;)

I originally had:

> Flag the post for moderator attention. One of the other moderators can then review the decision.

as one of the things to do, but you can't actually flag a locked post so this isn't possible. You could flag another of your posts, but it's simpler to raise a question on meta.

Comment: Unfortunately locking prevents you from flagging I believe

Comment: @BenBrocka - You may be right there. I'll update.

Answer (score 4):

Study the FAQ, examine the close reasons, and figure out what you need to do differently in order not to run afoul of the site standards.

A complaint without even a link to the problem question isn't helpful. It doesn't give us anything to work with to help you!

Comment: No, my question is not a complaint but as a general know-how, and I said locked and not closed. And yes I downvoted you because you never read my question properly.

Comment: @Dee Jay This answer is just as valid for "locked" questions as it is "closed" questions.

Comment: @BeofettL I need moderator explanation for this.

Comment: @deejay: Locks typically happen on closed questions, but even in the case of an open one, it is usually because someone involved had refused to cooperate and act inside of site guidelines. Also, for general reference you should ask on meta.so not here.

Comment: @Caleb: Again please reread my question, I said `What should an OP do if his question on programmers.stackexchange.com being locked by a moderator`

Comment: @deejay: I've read your question. It's one sentence and pretty easy to grok. The trouble is it doesn't give us anything to work with. Without a case study on this site there is nothing much too be said. Your inclusion of this site's URL is pedantic and doesn't make this nota general reference question that belongs on MSO.

Comment: @Caleb: Since you ask me, then I respond, I was banned from MSO after I posted 2 feature requests. I make this clear. This is for your info and not a complaint.

Comment: Actually, @Dee... you asked *three* questions. Two were closed and then deleted. All were down-voted heavily.

Comment: @Mr. CRT♦: I don't get you. Any relation to my current question?

Comment: @Mr.CRT: Oh, you mean MSO questions? By the way those figure were given by genesis-φ. See this post  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107546/what-do-you-think-about-a-notify-me-again-later-feature/107553#comment277113_107553

Comment: @Dee You've received multiple moderator explanations. You don't seem willing to accept them, yet you also don't seem willing to explain why (or to provide any more useful information to help put things in context). Incidentally, I do not believe that genesis-φ can see deleted questions, so the fact that he cited a different figure on the number of poor-quality MSO questions that resulted in your ban is irrelevant.

Comment: @Beofett: someone told me genesis-φ is SE employee and can access all info as he wishes.

Comment: @DeeJay Whoever told you that is incorrect.  All SE employees will be identified on sites by either the ♦ or Ψ symbol (the former are employees and moderators, the later are a special team specifically targeting site promotion and who have no special powers anyway).  Genesis has neither of those symbols attached to his screen name.

Comment: @Beofett: Noted.